# Cucumber/Gherkin - Is it acceptable to place "When" terms within the "Background"?

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

My Cucumber/Gherkin test covers some basic creation and deletion, however the first scenario covers a process that is a prerequisite to the subsequent scenarios.

**For example:** If we have a new car with contents found within an array of some sort (initially empty since it is new)

```
Scenario: Adding an item to the car
    Given I have bought a new car
    When I add fluffy dice to the mirror
    Then There should be fluffy dice found in the car

Scenario: Removing an item from the car
    Given I have bought a new car
    When I add fluffy dice to the mirror
        And I remove fluffy dice from the mirror
    Then There should be no items found in the car

Scenario: Add multiple items to the car
    Given I have bought a new car
    When I add fluffy dice to the mirror
        And I a bobble head to the dashboard
    Then there should be 2 items in the car
```

I know that I can abstract the line `Given I have bought a new car` into a `Background:`, but what about adding the `When I add fluffy dice to the mirror` since this is present throughout all scenarios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is doable - you basically just change when to and ))

```
Background: 
    Given I have bought a new car
    And I add fluffy dice to the mirror
```

Comment: Is this still within the spirit of Cuc/Gher, or would we be seen to be abusing its power?

Comment: Yes, you basically prevent repeating in multi-scenario feature. As it is mentioned [here](https://blog.codeship.com/cucumber-best-practices/):

    5. Use backgrounds wisely
    If you use the same steps at the beginning of all scenarios of a feature, put them into the feature’s Background. Background steps are run before each scenario. But take care that you don’t put too many steps in there as your scenarios may become hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Going off of Cucumber's own docs, it was a little confusing almost saying that you should only put `Given` attributes in there.

Comment: What would be your suggestion regarding steps reused in scenarios, but that aren't the initial steps that can be grouped into a `Background`? I just get a bit tired of seeing the same steps 50 times...

Comment: Had not managed to simplify :( Try to ensure your application logic checks are not being duplicated, i.e. check that "car has been bought" in less scenarios of car buying...

Comment: Unfortunately the code I'm refactoring is using a teardown service between each scenario :-( I'm sure I can come up with something!